# Can I concatenate an if else statement that returns a string to server-side rendered HTML elements?

Tags: javascript, server-side-rendering, serverside-javascript

I'm working on a web app that must display one or another value depending on the state of a boolean value. I need it to display "ON" if my `var` "value" is `true`, else it must display "OFF".

I did this code, and I was pretty sure it was going to work, but I was mistaken:

```
var value = true // actually this changes over time
var s = new String();
s += '<span style="color:white; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold;">'+ "ALRM H2S:" +'</span>';
s += '<span style="color: orange; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold;">'+ if(value){return "ON"} else {return "OFF"} +'</span>';

return s;
```

I get a "Syntax error at line (#3)". I think that the problem must be that I can't concatenate that `if` `else` statement, even if they return a `string`, with the rest of the HTML elements.

What I'm doing wrong?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, you cannot have an if statement inline like that, so a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) is what you should use in this case. You can use it like so:

```js
var value = true; // actually this changes over time
var s = new String();
s += '<span style="color:white; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold;">' + "ALRM H2S:" + "</span>";
s += '<span style="color: orange; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold;">' + (value ? "ON" : "OFF") + "</span>";

return s;
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run a conditional statement while adding strings. My suggestion would be to you an arrow function that returns a string.

```
var value = true // actually this changes over time
var s = new String();
var ifOn = () => { value? "ON" :"OFF"}
s += '<span style="color:white; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold;">'+ "ALRM H2S:" +'</span>';
s += '<span style="color: orange; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold;">' + ifOn() +'</span>'
```

Comment: Analyzing this approach, it should work perfectly!  However, it also throws a syntax error... what could it be?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for your great answers!

I came up with this not so good solution as yours, however, it works:

```
var s = new String();

var h2sStatus;

if(value){ h2sStatus = "ON"} else {h2sStatus = "OFF"}

s += '<span style="color:white; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold;">ALARM H2S: </span>';

s += '<span style="color: orange; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold;">'+ h2sStatus  +'</span>';

return s;
```

I post it in case it can be of help to someone.